# Replace white space and format string

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I can't find how to replace the `whiteSpace` in a `aggregate` request with MongoDB and how to delete a part of a string.(I'll probably need to use a regex).

**Example of my document:**

```
{
    "_id": "57dfa5c9xxd76b65426d5cca",
    "battle_id": "5744f01d1ad716a349c4999a",
    "is_first": false,
    "title": "division 1 #3"
},    
{
    "_id": "13dfa529dxd123x5426d5ccb",
    "battle_id": "1244x51d1aq546a349c423rcc",
    "is_first": true,
    "title": "division gold #5"
}
```

**What I'm doing currently:**

```
.project({
    "battle_id": "$battle_id",  
    "is_first": {
        $cond: [
            { $eq : ["$rank" , 1] }, 
            true, 
            false
        ]
    }, 
    "title": { $toLower: "$battle.title" }
})
```

Is it possible to change each white space by `"_"` character or do I need to do it in a `forEach()` after the request?

Moreover, is it possible to format the string to never return me the `#3` for example?

**Result that I need (changes are in title):**

```
{
    "_id": "57dfa5c9xxd76b65426d5cca",
    "battle_id": "5744f01d1ad716a349c4999a",
    "is_first": false,
    "title": "division_1"
},    
{
    "_id": "13dfa529dxd123x5426d5ccb",
    "battle_id": "1244x51d1aq546a349c423rcc",
    "is_first": true,
    "title": "division_gold"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace white space and format string by using [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) and [Array#map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get the `result`:

```js
var arr = [{"_id": "57dfa5c9xxd76b65426d5cca","battle_id": "5744f01d1ad716a349c4999a","is_first": false,"title": "division 1 #3"},{"_id": "13dfa529dxd123x5426d5ccb","battle_id": "1244x51d1aq546a349c423rcc","is_first": true,"title": "division gold #5"}],
    result = arr.map(i => {
      return {
        '_id': i._id,
        'battle_id': i.battle_id,
        'is_first': i.is_first,
        'title': i.title.replace(/\s#[0-9]+/g, '').replace(/\s/,'_')
      };
    });

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank's, so there is no proper solution to do it in the directly with mongo. So thank's to you, i ll continue on this way.